# Combining yaw and pitch together

Tags: c++, math, glm-math

Why doesn't resultA equal resultB? I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Can you give me an explanation?

```
float alpha = glm::radians(45.0f);

glm::mat4 xRot(glm::vec4(1, 0, 0, 0),
               glm::vec4(0, glm::cos(alpha), glm::sin(alpha), 0),
               glm::vec4(0, -glm::sin(alpha), glm::cos(alpha), 0),
               glm::vec4(0, 0, 0, 1));

glm::mat4 yRot(glm::vec4(glm::cos(alpha), 0, -glm::sin(alpha), 0),
               glm::vec4(0, 1, 0, 0),
               glm::vec4(glm::sin(alpha), 0, glm::cos(alpha), 0),
               glm::vec4(0, 0, 0, 1));

glm::vec4 vec(0, 0, -100, 1);

glm::vec4 resultA(0.0f);
glm::vec4 resultB(0.0f);

resultA = xRot  * yRot * vec; //(-70.7107, 50, -50, 1)
resultB = yRot  * xRot * vec; //(-50, 70.7107, -50, 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

3D rotations don't commute in general, except in very special cases. Thus:

```
xRot * yRot != yRot * xRot
```

Essentially what you're doing with the above is proving the point :)

See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property